# how to count svg elements for performance tuning in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, svg

I have a javascript web app which is dynamically graphing+animating various datasets in SVG, and want to do some performance tuning because there can be thousands of SVG elements. I am looking for a count of the visible or significant elements for comparison.  My working but crude first attempt is below.  Would like to at least get counts by each SVG element rather than the document-wide document.getElementsByTagName() call.

```
   let svgs = document.getElementsByTagName("svg"),
       totalChildren = 0,
       childCounts = [];

   for( let i=0; i<svgs.length; i++ ){
       let svg = svgs[i];
       totalChildren += svg.childElementCount;
       childCounts.push( svg.childElementCount );
   }

   let tags = [ "clipPath", "circle", "rect", "path", "text" ],
       tagMessage = "";
   tags.forEach( tagName => {
       tagMessage += ( document.getElementsByTagName(tagName).length + " ");
   });

   console.log( 'SVG element counts are: totalChildren='+ totalChildren, " SVG childElementCounts:", childCounts, " by tag:", tagMessage + tags );
```

Sample output:

SVG element counts are: totalChildren=2721  SVG childElementCounts: (6) [1312, 5, 30, 4, 4, 1366]  by tag: 1313 1317 2673 21 11 clipPath,circle,rect,path,text

Comment: If the SVG elements are being dynamically inserted, perhaps you should encapsulate the dynamic insertion with a function that keeps a reference to the amount currently in the document, that way you don't have to explicitly query it later.

Comment: I already have that, but since there are multiple routines modifying the DOM, including Raphael and some plugins, wanted something independent to assess complexity, for example clipping paths, glow effects, etc.  For example I thought there was only one SVG layer, document reports 6, so I wanted to understand it better. Other than just wading through the document in the elements section of the debugger which has tons of data I am not interested in.

Comment: The performance of a rect with a complex filter as a fill will be wildly different to a rect with a simple fill colour so I don't see what the point is of this exercise.

Comment: Good, yes, so if I believed you, how would I count the number of rects with one kind of filter versus a simple fill color? I'm looking for a simple answer to the question where I ignore the thousands of parameters in the DOM and shorten the

Comment: "...shorten the description of the SVG complexity".